# Unselecting ng-options dropdown in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a select dropdown using ng-options that is used to filter a list on the page.When the page loads, the dropdown is blank and no filtering has occurred.

[image: on initial page load]

When I select an option, filtering happens properly, but the blank option disappears, and thus I am forced to have a department-filtered version of the list unless I refresh the page and start over:

Before:
[image: Before Selecting, the blank option still there]

After:
[image: Blank option gone]

Here is my code:

.html file:

```
         Department:
        <select ng-model="search.SubDepartmentID" ng-options="d.SubDepartmentID as d.DepartmentLabel for d in DepartmentList"></select>
        
        <br />
        <div class="span10">
            <!--Body content-->

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="(index,e) in filteredEmployees | filter:search | orderBy:orderProp | startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"
                    class="thumbnail employee-listing">
                    <a href="#/Employee/{{e.EmployeeID}}" class="thumb">
                        <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" ng-src="../Images/CurrentEmployees/{{e.ImageName}}"></a>
                    <p><a href="#/Employee/{{e.EmployeeID}}">{{e.FullName}}</a></p>
                    <p>{{e.Department}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I want to be able to return it to the blank option so that I have a completely unfiltered list.  Doing a value="" option or just completely empty  doesn't work, because it's filtering based on value, and nothing matches the empty value.

Any Help or direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the responses, I took a mix of a few of your responses, added in a watch and achieved what I wanted, here is what I ended up with:

```
<select ng-model="search.SubDepartmentID" ng-options="d.SubDepartmentID as d.DepartmentLabel for d in DepartmentList"><option value=""></option></select>
```

So I did add the empty value, but I modified the watch that I already had in my controller to set the $scope.search.SubDepartmentID to undefined if it comes back null:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[search.$, search.Status, search.SubDepartmentID]', function (newSearch) {
    if ($scope.search != undefined) {
        if ($scope.search.SubDepartmentID == null) {
            $scope.search.SubDepartmentID = undefined;
        }
    }
});
```

The $scope.search.SubDepartmentID is undefined upon page load, and resetting it to undefined on select of the empty value did the trick!

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Nice solution. The filtering was changed in angular 1.2.0 so that null is considered a valid search value whereas undefined means that the filter is not applied.

Answer (score 3):

You need to place a blank option in onload

```
<select ng-model="search.SubDepartmentID" ng-options="d.SubDepartmentID as d.DepartmentLabel for d in DepartmentList">
    <option value=''></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Very cool! Just watch out, because if someone selects that blank option, it will be `null` which is different than the default unselected select value of `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the first answer works of a value=' ' since your question made it sound like you had tried that. I would set a value = to a function that deletes the variable used to filter. That way it re-instantiates and sets to undefined again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have complex filtering requirements you may be better off using a function as a filter.

Add an empty option to the select:

```
<select ng-model="...." ng-options="....">
    <option value=''>Choose a value</option>
</select>
```

Supply a function to the filter that should return true for all employees that should be shown:

```
<li ng-repeat="e in filteredEmployees | filter:filterEmployee>{{e.FullName}}</li>
```

On the controller:

```
$scope.filterEmployee = function(employee) {
    return !search.SubDepartmentID || employee.SubDepartmentID == search.SubDepartmentID    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't involve adding an extra $watch to your controller.

As has been suggested, the first step is to add an empty option to the select:

```
<select ng-model="typeFilter" ng-options="i.value as i.label for i in types">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

However, if you are using this value as a filter, this won't work as expected, since (as pointed out by @GruffBunny), in angular 1.2+, empty selects are interpreted as null values, so the filter is searching for null vs not applying the filter.

I found a simple fix to this problem:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items | filter:{type: typeFilter || undefined}'>
  {{item.name}} {{ item.type}}
</div>
```

That is, if the value of typeFilter is not truthy, set the filter value to undefined (i.e. don't apply the filter). Note that if `0` or `false` are valid filter values, you'll need to get a bit more nuanced. I haven't tested this, but something along these lines should work in that case:

```
 <div ng-repeat='item in items | filter:{type: typeFilter !== null ? typeFilter : undefined}'>
  {{item.name}} {{ item.type}}
</div>
```

Hopefully this saves someone some head-scratching :)